# How do you pass an ArrayList to another Class? Java

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I'm having trouble with my code, I'm not too sure what is going wrong.

(Please ignore the method and class names. I didn't know about the rules till today.)

I need to send an ArrayList from one class to another class.

Here is the class which I want to pass the array to.

```
public class AdminUserController implements Initializable {

UserData callClass = new UserData();

public void CreateUser(){
    callClass.main();
    out.println("Button Clicked");
    ArrayTest(ArrayList <Users> myUsers);
}

public void ArrayTest(ArrayList <Users> myUsers){
    for (int i = 0; i < myUsers.toArray().length; i++) {
        if (myUsers.get(i) != null) {
            for (Users aMyUsers : myUsers) {
                if (aMyUsers != null) {
                    out.println("This should display 10 times");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is isolated and isn't the full program.

CreateUser is a JAVA FX button (I'm not sure if it's possible to pass parameters via that way)

I think the problem trying to get the ArrayTest method to activate.

It needs to be activated via button press.

Here is the class in which the ArrayList located.

```
        package BunnyCorp.Classes;

    import BunnyCorp.Controllers.AdminUserController;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class UserData{

        public void main(){
        ArrayList <Users> myUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        Users myUsers0 = new Users(1000, "admin", "password", "N/A", " N/A", " N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "ADMIN");
        Users myUsers1 = new Users(1001, "lecturer", "capitalism", "Adam", "Smith", "127 High St", "Kirkcaldy", "KY5D8F", "03069990552", "16/06/1723", "STAFF");
        Users myUsers2 = new Users(1002, "president", "economics", "Ronald", "Reagan", "56 Bel-Air", "Los Caldy", "KY8BD2", "80865390552", "06/02/1911", "STAFF");
        Users myUsers3 = new Users(1003, "engineer", "memeword", "Tim", "Berners-Lee", "15 Westwood Place", "London", "KY9WWW", "07700900262", "08/06/1955", "STAFF");
        Users myUsers4 = new Users(1004, "polymath", "monalisa", "Leonardo", "da Vinci", "23 Via Mozza", "Florence", "FL9MLA", "07700900466", "15/04/1452", "MEMBER");
        Users myUsers5 = new Users(1005, "theoryman", "sexyphysics", "Richard", "Feynman", "Trump Tower", "New York", "NY5JEA", "03069990552", "11/05/1918", "MEMBER");
        Users myUsers6 = new Users(1006, "destroyerofworlds", "nuclearwar", "Julius Robert", "Oppenheimer", "20 Trinity Site", "New Mexico", "NKW194", "03069990828", "22/04/1904", "MEMBER");
        Users myUsers7 = new Users(1007, "crashtest", "dummy", "Samuel", "Alderson", "11 Marina Dey Rey", "California", "MDR238", "03069990011", "21/10/1914", "CASUAL");
        Users myUsers8 = new Users(1008, "Zucc", "dadada", "Mark", "Zuckerberg", "1456 Edgewood Drive", "California", "EWD238", "06505434800", "14/05/1984", "CASUAL");
        Users myUsers9 = new Users(1009, "bigmoney", "money", "Bill", "Gates", "1835 73rd Ave", "Washington", "WSA039", "2067093140", "28/10/1955", "CASUAL");

        myUsers.add(myUsers0);
        myUsers.add(myUsers1);
        myUsers.add(myUsers2);
        myUsers.add(myUsers3);
        myUsers.add(myUsers4);
        myUsers.add(myUsers5);
        myUsers.add(myUsers6);
        myUsers.add(myUsers7);
        myUsers.add(myUsers8);
        myUsers.add(myUsers9);

        AdminUserController UserCreator = new AdminUserController();
        UserCreator.ArrayTest(myUsers);
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

I would appreciate help. I've been looking online for a solution, but I keep hitting walls.

Comment: `ArrayTest(ArrayList <Users> myUsers);` what's this line inside the constructor ?

Comment: You know this code is recursive right ? You will keep entering the constructor.. It will give you `StackOverflowException`

Comment: ArrayTest(ArrayList <Users> myUsers); this line should be replaced by ArrayTest(myUsers); where myUsers is object

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did in your constructor with calling the main method, but your printing method has several problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myUsers.toArray().length; i++) {
    if (myUsers.get(i) != null) {
        for (Users aMyUsers : myUsers) {
            if (aMyUsers != null) {
                out.println("This should display 10 times");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1/ There is no need to do myUser.toArray().length, use myUsers.size()
2/ After checking for null users in the if statement, just print it out, why traversing the list again with a loop? It would print the arraylist twice

Your function could have just be like this

```
for(Users aUser : myUsers){
  if(aUser!=null)
     System.out.println(aUser.toString());
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < myUsers.size(); i++){
   if(myUsers.get(i) != null)
      System.out.println(myUsers.get(i).toString());
}
```

If you're wondering if they array myUser exists when passed into the function, print out its size or the first element would suffice too. Debugging may help for these kinds of problem.